# SharePoint Designer 2007 email

Tags: 2007, workflow

Does anyone know if I can add condtional logic within a 'Send an Email' action in a workflow implemented in SPD 2007?

Thanks,
Nav

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you provide an example of what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conditional logic to the workflow step itself.  If you need to send a second workflow for a different condition, you would need another step and put a condition on it also.